# getting variable value from previous intent

Tags: android, android-intent

i just like to ask how can I get a value from a previous intent to use it to the next activity in my android app.

--> this is my first activity

```
    public class Input extends Activity {

ArrayAdapter<String> m_adapter;
ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

Button bt;
EditText et,et2;
TextView tv;
ListView lv;
int count = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_input);

    //add

    bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text1);
    et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text2);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    final String input = et.getText().toString();
    final String input2 = et2.getText().toString();

    bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                String input = et.getText().toString();
                String input2 = et2.getText().toString();
                if(null!=input&&input.length()>0){     

                m_listItems.add(input);
                m_listItems.add(input2);
                m_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                count++;

              }
            }
        });


    //shazaam
    Button random = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    random.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Intent shazam = new Intent(Input.this,Random.class);
            startActivity(shazam);

        }

    });


}
```

I can't come up with the second activity because I need to utilize the variables, and the list that I made from the activity above.
What I'm planning to do is get the count value, and the list items that i had entered.
I'm a newbie in creating such apps, its really taking all my time.
thanks for your help in advance. :)

In addition to that, I think my app has a problem, I don't know what to do, everytime I press a button, it blacks out but does not crash but instead goes to the front page of the app.

Comment: put the data in the `shazam` intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That use case is one of the reasons intents are used, to pass extra values to the activity.

```
Intent shazam = new Intent(Input.this,Random.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putInt("count", count);
b.putStringArrayList("list", m_listItems);
shazam.putExtras(b);
startActivity(shazam);
```

then on the other activity:

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
int count = b.getInt("count");
ArrayList<String> list = b.getStringArrayList("list");
```